# How to trace all paths of a tree like data structure?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

Let's say I have a nested object like so:

```
{
  label: 'parent',
  eyeColor: 'brown',
  kids: [
    {
      label: 'kid_0',
      eyeColor: 'brown',
      kids: [
        {
          label: 'kid_0_0',
          eyeColor: 'green',
          kids: []
        },
        {
          label: 'kid_0_1',
          eyeColor: 'brown',
          kids: [
            {
              label: 'kid_0_1_0',
              eyeColor: 'brown',
              kids: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'kid_1',
      eyeColor: 'brown',
      kids: [
        {
          label: 'kid_1_0',
          eyeColor: 'brown',
          kids: []
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'kid_2',
      eyeColor: 'green',
      kids: []
    }
  ]
};
```

If I wanted to store all unique paths, how would I do so recursively? I've tried many attempts, but I can't seem to obtain unique paths (my paths build on top of previous paths).

So my expected output would be:

```
[
  ['parent', 'kid_0', 'kid_0_0],
  ['parent', 'kid_0', 'kid_0_1, kid_0_1_0],
  ['parent', 'kid_1', 'kid_1_0],
  ['parent', 'kid_2]
]
```

But if I wanted to stop the path when I found a kid or node with an `eyeColor` other than `brown`, the path would stop there. Then what would have to change to obtain the following:

```
[
  ['parent', 'kid_0', 'kid_0_1, kid_0_1_0],
  ['parent', 'kid_1', 'kid_1_0],
]
```

This is my current code, which is now error-ing out b/c of maximum call stack.

```
var printPaths = function(node, color) {
  var paths = [];

  var trackPath = function(obj, feature, path) {
    if (obj.eyeColor === 'brown') {
      path.push(node.label);
    } else if (obj.eyeColor !== 'brown') {
      paths.push(path);
    } else if (obj.kids.length === 0) {
      paths.push(path);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.kids.length; i++) {
      trackPath(obj.kids[i], feature, path)
      path.pop();
    }
  };

  trackPath(node, color, []);
  return paths; 
}
```

Comment: Please show us your attempts even when they didn't work.

Comment: @Bergi I posted my broken code. I was hesitant to post it because I wanted to see how more experienced programmers approach the problem.

Comment: That approach looks exactly fine - except that [arrays are reference values and need to be copied explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572). So drop the `.pop()` call and instead make the recursive call a `trackPath(obj, feature, path.slice())`

Comment: @Bergi do you mean `obj.kids[i]`? I added the `.slice()`, but then I just get `[ [ 'parent', 'parent' ],
  [ 'parent', 'parent', 'parent' ],
  [ 'parent', 'parent' ] ]`. It doesn't do as I expect.

Comment: No, I mean the `path`. It's referring to the exact same array everywhere, to the array you created in the initial `trackPath(node, color, []);` call.

Comment: Btw, the `obj.kids.length === 0` path is never taken. The eyecolor always already is brown or not brown.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, regarding that, I posted an example that didn't cover all cases, but the idea is that when it reaches the end of a path or when it encounters a non-brown eye color, it would push that path to `paths`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122060/discussion-between-alanh-and-bergi).

Comment: @AlanH but shouldn't the path stop at "parent"? because "parent" already has a child with an eyeColor other than green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is mostly fine, the only problem was that [assignment or argument passing doesn't copy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572). Introduce a `slice()` call into the recursion:

```
function printPaths(node, color) {
  var paths = [];

  function trackPath(obj, feature, path) {
    if (obj.eyeColor !== feature) { // found target
      paths.push(path);
      return;
    } // else continue
    path.push(obj.label);

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.kids.length; i++) {
      trackPath(obj.kids[i], feature, path.slice());
//                                        ^^^^^^^^
    }
  }

  trackPath(node, color, []);
  return paths;
}
```

Comment: @AlanH: The `feature` thing was different, after my edit it should behave identical to your answer

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach, I had to rewrite your logic as well as use array copying using slice

```
var printPaths = function(node, color) {
  var paths = [];

  var trackPath = function(obj, feature, path) {
    //debugger;
    path.push(obj.label);

    if (obj.eyeColor === 'brown') {
      if (obj.kids.length == 0) {
        paths.push(path.slice());
      }
      else {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.kids.length; i++) {
          trackPath(obj.kids[i], feature, path);
        }
      }
    } 


    path.pop();
  };

  trackPath(node, color, []);
  return paths; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that I ended up getting to work. I had help from @Bergi, but his solution doesn't quite do what I need. This solution pasts all the tests I wrote.

```
var printPaths = function(node, color) {
  var paths = [];

  var trackPath = function(obj, feature, path) {    
    // if the current node has the desired property, push that
    // to the current path, then continue checking checking
    // if there are any children (two if statements down)
    if (obj.eyeColor === feature) {
      path.push(obj.label);
    } 
    // if we encounter a path that isn't our desired property,
    // don't push the current node on to the current path, but instead
    // just push the failed path, and return, so that it doesn't
    // continue to check
    if (obj.eyeColor !== feature) {
      paths.push(path);
      return;
    }
    // if we're at a leaf node, i.e we had a full successful path
    // (everyone had brown eyes)
    if (obj.kids.length === 0) {
      paths.push(path);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.kids.length; i++) {
      trackPath(obj.kids[i], feature, path.slice())
    }
  };

  trackPath(node, color, []);
  return paths; 
}
```